# Three months in a row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help. How to find users who have refueled 50 or more liters every month for 3 months in a row? Customers are counted on the last month of the three-month period.

I'm new to SQL and only guessed to filter out customers who refuel more than 50 liters per month.

```
SELECT [Client]
      ,SUM([Litr]) AS Volume
      ,DATEPART(mm, [Date_transaction]) AS Month_num
      ,DATEPART(yyyy, [Date_transaction]) AS Year_num
FROM [dbo].[Транзакции]
GROUP BY [Client], DATEPART(mm, [Date_transaction]), DATEPART(yyyy, [Date_transaction])
HAVING SUM([Litr]) >= 50
```

I received this table:

```
    |Client|Volume          |Month_num|Year_num|
    |:-----|:---------------|:--------|:-------|
    |33    |52,7497194163861|8        |2019    |
    |33    |58,1573308846036|9        |2019    |
    |33    |148,852157943067|10       |2019    |
    |33    |61,2182430364249|12       |2019    |
    |55    |73,0741761044791|1        |2019    |
    |55    |136,802367105397|3        |2019    |
    |58    |88,0522395673911|7        |2019    |
    |58    |140,965207631874|8        |2019    |
    |58    |130,20099989797 |9        |2019    |
    |181   |507,009488827671|6        |2019    |
```

Desired result:

```
|Month_num|COUNT(Client)|
|:--------|-------------| 
|9        | 1           | (Client 58)
|10       | 1           | (Client 33)
```

Comment: Please help us with what you've tried so far?

Comment: how have you calculated client count ?

Comment: I screened out from a sample of users who refueled less than 50 liters per month

SELECT [Client]
   ,SUM([Litr]) AS Volume
   ,DATEPART(mm, [Date_transaction]) AS Month_num
   ,DATEPART(yyyy, [Date_transaction]) AS Year_num
FROM [dbo].[Транзакции]
GROUP BY [Client], DATEPART(mm, [Date_transaction]), DATEPART(yyyy, [Date_transaction])
HAVING SUM([Litr]) >= 50

Comment: The desired table is just an example of what the answer should look like. Clients are summed up according to the principle: the last day of the third month. That is, the user refueled in January, February, March. Every month 50 liters. So it gets into the final table in the month of March

Comment: where is Feb month in your sample? Also your output has month=4 but in sample there is no such month. Is it correct ?

Comment: If there is no month in the sample, then the client has not refueled in it or has refueled less than 50 liters

Comment: Please edit the question with what you tried.

Comment: I think example will be better if you share transaction date instead of month and year.

Comment: I reasoned so that I found the amount of liters that each user refueled per month and excluded those who refueled less 50 liters. According to the conditions of the problem, the volumes of monthly refueling are compared.

Comment: Added a link to the original table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can group by `Client` and the start of each month. Then filter out all rows with `SUM(tr.Litr) < 50`.

Now we can use the `LAG` window function to check if the previous two rows were the previous two months.

The final result is simply the count of clients who satisfy that condition

```sql
SELECT
    MonthStart,
    NumOfClients = COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT
        tr.Client,
        v.MonthStart,
        PrevMonth1 = LAG(v.MonthStart, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY tr.Client ORDER v.MonthStart),
        PrevMonth2 = LAG(v.MonthStart, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY tr.Client ORDER v.MonthStart)
    FROM dbo.Транзакции tr
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
        DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(tr.Date_transaction), MONTH(tr.Date_transaction), 1)
    ) ) v(MonthStart)
    GROUP BY tr.Client, v.MonthStart
    HAVING SUM(tr.Litr) >= 50
) trGrouped
WHERE DATEDIFF(month, PrevMonth1, MonthStart)   = 1
  AND DATEDIFF(month, PrevMonth2, PrevMonth1) = 1
GROUP BY MonthStart;
```

Comment: MS SQL Managment Studio writes that Invalid column name "MonthStart" and "MonthEnd". What is meant? Simply renaming does not solve the problem.

Comment: Whoops sorry, fixed

Comment: The last thing I wanted to clarify is how to add a column in which the received number of clients from NumOfClients will be multiplied by 50? It is impossible to add to SELECT from above. An error is thrown: Incorrect syntax around the "trGrouped" construct.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, maybe `NumOfClients = COUNT(*) * 50` or something like that?

Comment: I want to add a new column with NumOfClient = COUNT () * 50. So that in the end the script shows three columns: Month, NumOfCluent and NumOfCluent * 50

Comment: OK so just change the start of the query to `SELECT MonthStart, NumOfClients = COUNT(*), NumOfClients50 = COUNT(*) * 50`

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, how to display customer numbers?

Comment: Well you have already aggregated, so you can't get that easily. You could use `STRING_AGG(tr.Client, ', ')` if your version supports it. Or you could remove the `GROUP BY` and use window functions instead

Comment: Where to insert STRING_AGG (tr.Client, ',')?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235032/discussion-between-charlieface-and-andrey).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

scripts for table and insert data. Although It was expected from @Andrey

```
create table #test(client int, litre decimal(10, 5), Date_transaction date)

insert into #test values (33    ,52.7497194163861,'8/1/2019')    
insert into #test values (33    ,58.1573308846036,'9/1/2019')    
insert into #test values (33    ,148.852157943067,'10/1/2019')    
insert into #test values (33    ,61.2182430364249,'12/1/2019')    
insert into #test values (55    ,73.0741761044791,'1/1/2019')    
insert into #test values (55    ,136.802367105397,'3/1/2019')    
insert into #test values (58    ,88.0522395673911,'7/1/2019')    
insert into #test values (58    ,140.965207631874,'8/1/2019')    
insert into #test values (58    ,130.20099989797 ,'9/1/2019')    
insert into #test values (181   ,507.009488827671,'6/1/2019')
```

Solution Script

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct client)client, max(month)month
FROM
(
    select t1.client, t1.litre, t1.Date_transaction,(DATEPART(mm, t1.Date_transaction)+2)month
    from 
    #test t1
    inner join #test t2 ON (t1.client = t2.client and (DATEPART(mm, t1.Date_transaction)+1) = DATEPART(mm, t2.Date_transaction))
    inner join #test t3 ON (t1.client = t3.client and (DATEPART(mm, t1.Date_transaction)+2) = DATEPART(mm, t3.Date_transaction))
    where t1.litre>50
)T
GROUP BY client
```

Comment: Can't imagine a triple self-join is going to perform well, also `DATEPART(mm, ` only works in the same year

Answer (score 0):

> How to find users who have refueled 50 or more liters every month for 3 months in a row?

I would use aggregation and `lag()`.  To get the last month where this occurs:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.Client, v.yyyymm,
             SUM(t.Litr) AS Volume,
             LAG(v.yyyymm, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY t.Client ORDER BY v.yyyymm) as prev2_yyyymm
      FROM [dbo].[Транзакции] t CROSS APPLY
           (VALUES (DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(t.Date_transaction), MONTH(t.Date_transaction), 1))
           ) v(yyyymm)
      GROUP BY t.Client, v.yyyymm
      HAVING SUM(Litr) >= 50
     ) t
WHERE prev2_yyyymm = DATEADD(MONTH, -2, yyyymm);
```

If you want to aggregate by month:

```
SELECT yyyymm, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT t.Client, v.yyyymm,
             SUM(t.Litr) AS Volume,
             LAG(v.yyyymm, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY t.Client ORDER BY v.yyyymm) as prev2_yyyymm
      FROM [dbo].[Транзакции] t CROSS APPLY
           (VALUES (DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(t.Date_transaction), MONTH(t.Date_transaction), 1))
           ) v(yyyymm)
      GROUP BY t.Client, v.yyyymm
      HAVING SUM(Litr) >= 50
     ) t
WHERE prev2_yyyymm = DATEADD(MONTH, -2, yyyymm)
GROUP BY yyyymm;
```

What is this doing?  The inner query is basically your query with some refinements:

- `yyyymm` is a date, more convenient than storing the year and month in the same column.
- The `CROSS APPLY` is just a convenient way of defining the `yyyymm` alias.
- `prev2_yyyymm` gets the second time previously when the client met the condition.

The outer query implements the logic:  If `prev2_yyyymm` is exactly two months ago, then we have three months in a row that meet the condition.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6204a72911bd737a85378fece288381a) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: MS SQL Managment Studio writes that Invalid syntax near construct "(" in this line SUM(t.Litr) AS Volume. What is meant? Simply removing the parenthesis does not solve the problem.

Comment: @Andrey . . . There was a missing comma in the previous row.  I added a db<>fiddle to illustrate the working code.